# IBM ODM : Verbalization for boolean functions in XOM

Tags: ibm-odm

I am new to ODM and I was trying to play around with verbalization. I have a question here.
Suppose there is a String field “discountDate” in my XOM and I need to write a rule like 
if the discount date of sale is{not} having date format "dd/mm/yyyy" 
then {do something}

To write such kind of rule how should my verbalization be? This is my XOM class : -
 [image: XOM Class]

The respective Verbalization which I have given in BOM is :-

[image]

My question here is that for the verbalization I am able to only give a Positive verbalization here like “{0} is having date format {1}”. Instead of giving an else condition in the Rule is there any way to give verbalization like ““{0} is not having date format {1}”
Do we need to write two separate function in the XOM one that returns true by default for that a positive verbalization and one that returns negative for that a negative verbalization?? Or is there any other better way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little clunky, but you can write the condition in the rule as:

**it is not true that** the discount date of sale is having date format "dd/mm/yyyy"